# How to line up text boxes and balance them out?

Tags: html, css

I have 12 text boxes as shown below. I want to line them up so the same number of boxes appear on the top and bottom always. For example, it might be 2 rows of 6, or at another screen width it might be 3 rows of 4 boxes. I also want spaces in between the rows so it looks better. Lastly, they should all line up, I noticed my bottom row seems to have an extra space in it so the top and bottom rows are not aligned perfectly.

What is the best way to do this?

```
<input name="Neighborhood1" type="text" id="Neighborhood1">
<input name="Neighborhood2" type="text" id="Neighborhood2">
<input name="Neighborhood3" type="text" id="Neighborhood3">
<input name="Neighborhood4" type="text" id="Neighborhood4">
<input name="Neighborhood5" type="text" id="Neighborhood5">
<input name="Neighborhood6" type="text" id="Neighborhood6">
<input name="Neighborhood7" type="text" id="Neighborhood7">
<input name="Neighborhood8" type="text" id="Neighborhood8">
<input name="Neighborhood9" type="text" id="Neighborhood9">
<input name="Neighborhood10" type="text" id="Neighborhood10">
<input name="Neighborhood11" type="text" id="Neighborhood11">
<input name="Neighborhood12" type="text" id="Neighborhood12">
```

Comment: You could do it by writing your own CSS but also, if you are using bootstrap you could utilize the grid system http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid

Comment: Bootstrap grid system would solve your usecase . have a look at examples on [bootstrap examples](http://getbootstrap.com/examples/grid/)

Comment: Bootstrap looks interesting, but I would prefer to do this using just CSS if possible.

Comment: The part they're talking about using is strictly CSS only. Javascript only comes into play with special events like collapse and navigation.

Comment: Copy the CSS from Bootstrap, if you dont want to rely on it. For your purpose, all you need are following classes `row` ,`col-md-*`, `col-xs-*` there are more, but this will do. You dont need any js

Comment: Not clear, what is the problem of this? - http://jsfiddle.net/atmu9sz1/

Comment: There is no reason you need to use or even come near bootstrap. Just fix width them and display as inline-block.

Comment: sdcr - your fiddle above happens to line up because of the width of the sample, but if you move the margin slightly to the left, you end up with 2 rows of 5 and one last row of 2, which looks odd.

Comment: Kodlee, I tried the fixed width and display:inline-block and have the same issue. I ended up with 9 on the top and 3 on the bottom when I changed the browser width.

Comment: Press, when I mentioned I would like to use CSS, I meant is it possible to do using CSS without loading Bootstrap?

Comment: OK, I looked into Bootstrap and started using it. Thanks for recommending it. I was surprised how easy and nice it is to use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible without loading bootstrap. Basically what you want is a fluid layout for your 12 inputs at different breakpoints. I used Susy to do the calculations, but it's just about percentage widths and media queries really. Not sure if this is what you're looking for though.

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 319px) {
input {
    width: 100%;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 0;
    margin-right: 0;
  }
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 320px) and (max-width: 479px) {
input {
    width: 49.15254%;
    float: left;
    margin-right: 1.69492%;
}
input:nth-child(2n) {
    float: right;
    margin-right: 0;
  }
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/huijing/s341oej4/)